# How to create index of array in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have data like:

```
{ title : "Moby-Dick" ,
author : "Herman Melville" ,
published : 1851 ,
ISBN : 0451526996 ,
topics : [ "whaling" , "allegory" , "revenge" , "American" ,
"novel" , "nautical" , "voyage" , "Cape Cod" ]
}
```

I want to create index on topics like:

```
db.volumes.createIndex( { topics: 1 } )
```

How to use pymongo to create mongodb like this?

Answer (score 0):

On Python changes just a little bit then the console mode.
Soo, you need to use something like this

```
my_collection.create_index([("mike", pymongo.DESCENDING),("eliot", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

In your case, your can use just(because ascending is default):

```
db.volumes.createIndex("topics")
```

Source: [Pymongo Documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html)